# android app used to track devices

Tags: android, android-studio, location

I'm trying to create a app where I can track the location of the device.
I have created the general app which picks up my location, I can't find any info on a way to create a (master/slave) scenario.

Ideally id like to have it that I install  "slave" app on the devices which I can track using the "master"

Please assist if possible, I have been searching for weeks and have not been able to come up with anything.

Thank you

Comment: Create a slave app that uses GPS. This app should get the current coordinates every few minutes which can be triggered by a alarm manager. Send these coordinates to the master app using a push notification service like GCM.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the road map for this app , so here it is

**In Slave side app :**

1. You can make service class which can run and check the gps location and send it back to Master app through any mean like in msg or in push notification services.

   2. You can make use of alaram manager which can me triggered and send message to the Master app.
   3. Or you can make a Broad Cast Receiver which can detect any change in the gps location and  send message to the Master app

Keep in mind that you can use any channel to send the message , and the message should contain the gps location , like latitude and longitude

An Idea in my mind is that you can send the message using the data to the Master and in Master side you can track every incoming messages

If the message contain the location and your keyword then it is your desired message take out the locations and do what ever you want to do.

for example lat:xx.xxxxxx  lomg:xx.xxxxxx com.myapp.package

so if the message contains your package name then you can filter out the lat and long from the message and also delete that message ,

I have made such app using simple way I described above.

Edit :  Links exactly for your case just modify them and enjoy

[Plotting on Map](https://github.com/will-quast/android-location-demo/blob/master/application/src/main/java/com/williamquast/androidlocationdemo/FusedLocationActivity.java) and [Here is GPS Tracker class just use it in your project](https://github.com/knoppixmeister/android-gps-demo/blob/master/src/com/example/gps/GPSTracker.java)

I hope this is great help for you now

Comment: Thank you for the help, would you be able to assist me with the code as to how i can send the locations, iv been researching and i have not been able to find anything, all i have right now is the app that plots my location on a map @Coas Mckey

Comment: ill try add this to my existing code, Thank you for all the assistance.@Coas Mckey